# Composer installation issue for Magento 2 on WAMP

Tags: php, magento2, installation, composer

I'm trying to install magento 2 on WAMP Windows 10. I have downloaded. When i run it gives error

> Autoload error "Vendor autoload is not found. 
>   Please run 'composer install' under application root directory."

So i have googled & through stackoveflow Q/A. I have installed composer @ C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 where my php.exe
is located.

Curl & OpenSSl is enabled in WAMP.

Now when i go through magento-2 directory. It still saying

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about getting Composer installed on Windows 10 in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Composer Windows Installer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) adds `composer.bat` location (`C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`) to the system `PATH` environment variable automatically, but the Windows Command Prompt program need to be restarted to reread the new `PATH` value.

Comment: Ohh. Need to close command prompt & reopen again & it works :) . Small things matters. Thanks Dmirty.

Comment: Composer is installed. Still installation issue is not solved. " composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)   Downloading: Connecting...
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template/zipball/31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-QAA1LTF+2015-10-23+0413
to retrieve a token.

Comment: The new problem is irrelevant to your initial problem "'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: Ok  Dmitry. Got solution for that as well using this url http://tutorials.scrisoft.com/solved-enter-your-github-credentials-to-go-over-the-api-rate-limit/. Now able to install Magento 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

When I was installing Magento 2 I faced the same issue. As you may know, you can install composer easily. Then problem is how to proceed with next steps. If my assumption is correct you can try the following to solve this issue.

1. remove unwanted variable from **PATH**(Environment variable). Because, in my case I tried installing composer many times and I had been added the path multiple times. So finally, I figured out and removed unused variables. Anyway double check this **PATH** variable.
2. Make sure **PHP** also added in that variables.

I had defined the path variable as **E:\xamp\php\;C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\ComposerSetup\bin**

And close windows explorer and prompt window. Even if it is throwing the same error, restart your machine and try.